# Odd ping results : another device answers the ping

Tags: networking, local-area-network, ping

On my LAN network 192.168.0.x. My computer is linked to a small Netgear router 192.168.0.19.

On some ping requests, I get an answer from the router, not from the actual server.
On several requests targeting the same server, I might even get responses from both.

Example:

```
c:\>ping 192.168.0.17
Reply from 192.168.0.17: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=225

c:\>ping google.com
Reply from **192.168.0.19**: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=225

c:\>ping something_outside_the_Lan_that_do_not_answer_to_ping
Reply from **192.168.0.19**: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=225

c:\>ping something_INside_the_Lan_that_do_not_answer_to_ping
Destination unreachable
```

Why is that?
How can .19 answers "OK" ?

[image]

Comment: Can you actually ping 192.168.0.19 instead of a hostname that apparently resolves to that address? This looks like a DNS issue.

Comment: @Chris: no, 192.168.0.19 won't reply to ping. And I don't think any hostname is resolving to that address. It does not appear in my question, but google.com and all other things resolve to their respective IP.

Comment: I'm confused now. In your information above, pinging google.com shows a reply from 192.168.0.19. EDIT: Never mind, I see what you're getting at. What is your router using for it's DNS service?

Comment: Yes Chris, you're confused exactly as I am. Pinging Google gets me an answer from that tiny GS105E. It has no DNS configured. I've added a screenshot from its config ...

Comment: There should be somewhere that shows which DNS servers the Netgear is using. Also could you post an ipconfig from your system?

Comment: "which DNS servers the Netgear is using" why has it to use a DNS server ? Anyway, I have an answer ...

Comment: Good that you've solved it. In answer to your question, since your machine is possibly the DNS service on your router, your router will also need configuring with DNS forwarders - this is usually done dynamically via your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I upgraded the firmware to the newest found version, and that strange behaviour stopped.
The netgear  GS105E doesn't answser the pings to other devices anymore.

So it was probably a bug.
[I'm not sure about the details of the ping protocols, but the former behaviour of the router obviously defeat its purpose]

Comment: Please accept this answer so it doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions